# Are M branes fundamental?

Tags: string-theory, branes

In M theory, are M branes fundamental or are they made of something else? Are they made up of fields?

Say for instance the M2 brane is not fundamental, wouldn't that mean that the string is not fundamental since a string is a wrapped M2 brane?

Comment: The analogous question for strings: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46573/2451

Comment: Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/348412/50583

Comment: The concept of being "fundamental" or "made of something else" should be defined precisely...